# Can you guess? You won't be able to answer!

Tags: riddle, word

I am

> Half of nothing
>
> Part of one
>
> More or less
>
> Favorite of children
>
> But fully a villain!

Can you guess this word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is

> NO

> Half of nothing

> <strike>If you split by syllable, you get to 'halves' no-thing</strike> half of NONE is NO.

> Part of one

> <strike>the letters N and O are part of the word ONE</strike> NEO is also known as the ONE, and (keeping letters in order, and removing E), leaves NO.

> More or less

> in the phrase 'No more, No less'

> Favorite of children

> Some children seem to enjoy being awkward and saying 'No!' to parental requests

> But fully a villain!

> Dr No *fully* fits the bill here

Finally:

> Can you guess this word?

Is it a guess if I've supported my reasoning? No - I don't think *that's* a guess, it's an answer.

Comment: I reckon the intention for the first line is that rot13(AB vf unys bs ABJG)

Comment: @Stiv it could be! But I don't see any indication either way, so I will leave my answer as it is for now

Comment: rot13(Lbh unir rirelguvat evtug. Jnvg. AB. Vg vf unys bs Abar. Naq cneg bs HAB.)

Comment: @DrD that's... enigmatic